# Use condition in powerpivot (DAX)

Tags: dax

My problem is that I can't get the IF condition to work in powerpivot (using DAX).

According to manual the syntax is:

IF(logical_test>,, value_if_false) where I can omitt the "value if false" if i want.

I have a lot of columns and I try to make a new one based on condition from another column.

What I tried is =IF([TimeTypeCode]="400", [WorkingHours]) and that doesn't work. What I want my condition to do is that if [TimeType] is equal to 400, then i want to put the value from [WorkingHours] in my new column. How can i do this?

Comment: What's the column returning instead? Never had a problem with IF() calculated columns before.

Answer (score 0):

from what I see here the problem is the ="400", the "" you used tell dax thats a string type and you are trying to use it as a numeric value.

Try using

IF([TimeTypeCode]=400, [WorkingHours])

instead,

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The fact is that I'm trying to check against a string, not a numeric value. All columns in my table consist of strings.